# Change event listeners priority

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project I have JS module, that adds event listeners on click:

```
$('.next-step').on('click', function () {
    // do something
});
```

In another module I should create new event listeners that should work AFTER previous listener. Lets say I do something like this:

```
$('.next-step').find('#someId').on('click', function () {
   // do another things
});
```

The problem is that second listener always works before first. How can I change this sequence?

Comment: are you doing any server side call in first function.

Comment: no, but I should do it in second listener

Comment: @RomaKliuchko check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843261/jquery-event-priority

Answer (score -2):

You can use `setTimeout()` function to make it be excuted later.

```
$('.next-step').on('click', function () {
    setTimeout(
       function(){alert("foo");
    },100)
});
```

It will be executed 100 miliseconds later so you will be sure that other events already were executed.

**Note:** you can change 100 to 1, it will be enough.

Comment: You can change it to 0 (zero) or leave the argument out. It will still run later because it is executed asynchronously.